# How can you update Parent form from Child dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, dialog

Similar to Notepad's method 'Find' where you can find a certain word and the main form will highlight the word while keeping the Find dialog box focused.

Here's where I'm at so far:

[Main.cs] (Windows Form)

```
private new Find FindForm;
private delegate void FindNextCallback(int s, int l);

private cmdFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindForm = new Find(txtInput.Text);
    FindForm.FindNext += new FindEventHandler(FoundNext);
    FindForm.Show();
}
private void FoundNext(object sender, FindEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new FindNextCallback(SelectFoundText), new object[] { e.Start, e.Length });
}
private void SelectFoundText(int s, int l) { txtInput.Select(s, l); }
```

[Find.cs] (Windows Form)

```
private static FindEventArgs FindArgs;
public event FindEventHandler FindNext;

private void cmdFindNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindArgs = new FindEventArgs(startingPosition, selectionLength);
    FindNext?.Invoke(null, FindArgs);
}
```

My problem is that whenever the user clicks "Find Next" the Main form doesn't do anything until I actually close the Find form or manually Main.Focus().

Also, fairly new with creating my own events so any tips on proper ways, cleaner ways, shorter ways to write my code would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` in parent form is updating but it doesn't show its selected text as highlighted, You can set [`HideSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection(v=vs.110).aspx) property of text box to `false` to make it show selected text as highlighted always, even when the control doesn't have focus.

> You can use this property to keep text highlighted in a text box
>   control while another form or a dialog box has focus, such as a
>   spelling checker dialog box.